# Can't send message to some bot users in Telegram

Tags: http-get, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I made the bot in telegram which accepts some requests from users. My bot should send notifications about changes of the request status. I do it separate from my script by sending get request. But some users can not get the notification message, because this error **"{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 403,
    "description": "Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user"
}"** The user didn't block the bot. The bot blocked itself for some reason. I can't understand how it happens. What is the reason of blocking bot by the user unconsciously? I want write the guid for user "how do not block bot", but I don't know the reason. How I can solve this issue?

Here's my request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=<Your request status changed>&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "View", "callback_data": "<request_id>"}]]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your bot is blocked by users yet, need to click `RESTART` to unblock bot.

You can try it yourself by click `Stop Bot` in menu.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. The user said that didn't stop the bot. Can the bot stop for other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, revoking bot's token solved it.